# Passing multiple parameters with cursor.executemany?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django 1.8 and doing some raw SQL queries using `connection.cursor`.

My question is about how to safely supply multiple parameters to the cursor. Here is my code:

```
   cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT cost, id, date, org_id FROM mytable "
    query += " WHERE ("
    for i, c in enumerate(codes):
        query += "id=%s "
        if (i != len(codes)-1):
            query += ' OR '
    query += " AND "
    for i, c in enumerate(orgs):
        query += "org_id=%s "
        if (i != len(orgs)-1):
            query += ' OR '
    cursor.execute(query, tuple(codes), tuple(orgs))
```

But this gives me:

```
 TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I'm trying to follow [the PEP documentation on `execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14), it says that one can use `executemany` instead, but that doesn't seem to help either:

```
 cursor.executemany(query, [tuple(codes), tuple(orgs)])
```

I just can't follow the PEP documentation without an example. Could anyone help?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing more arguments to `execute` than it accepts. What you need is to combine the query's parameters into a single tuple. One way to do that is to use `itertools.chain` to chain both lists' elements into one iterable that can be used to create a single tuple:

```
import itertools
cursor.execute(query, tuple(itertools.chain(codes, orgs)))
```